# RDP user session stuck on "signing out" - server 2016

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2016

I've two admin accounts for a remote server, struggling with one of them. The password for both is due to expire in 5 days. Because I have to RDP through 3 other machines to reach this server I can't press ctrl-alt-end, so instead I run this command on the box I want to change the password of:

explorer.exe shell:::{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}

This has worked many times before, so I wasn't expecting any difficulty this time. I was logged in as user A, ran the above command, changed the username to B in the username box (so i'm changing the password for B while logged on as A)

But then the process just hung - 30 minutes on the "Changing password" screen with no change. Disconnecting/reconnecting RDP as user A just brings me back to the same jammed screen

I was able to remote into another server on the same domain (as user A), and issue a query followed by reset/logoff to try and disconnect the stuck session. That changed the message from "Changing password" to "Signing out" but it's still jammed.

I've also since logged into the same server (that A is jammed on) as user B (using the new password, so the change process has completed, it seems), and tried:

- use the task manager to try and sign off user A
- use RUNAS with user a's credentials, to run RESET and also LOGOFF

These had no effect either

Trying MSTSC with the /admin command line switch also brought me back to the same stuck session (when signing in as the stuck user A)

On the users tab of task manager User A in the tree has 4 sub nodes: Client Server Runtime process, Desktop Window Manager, Service Host: Unistack Service Group, Windows Logon Application, Windows Logon User Interface Host

The only one of these that can be force quit without threatening to shut down windows, is the last one. Quitting it removes the signing off message and leaves me with a black screen

I noted there are a few processes running, like Desktp Window Manager, that are started by users of the pattern DWM-nn - I think the nn is the session ID, but will force quitting the relevant DWM also bring about the apocalypse foretold by the Users tab of task manager?

How else should I approach signing this stuck user out?